# Iterate though a list of Dict Values and remove elements from that list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list of dictionaries like below:

```
Dict1 = [{'Title': 'Title1', 'Attributes':['name1.50', 'name2.40', 'name1.90']}, 
         {'Title': 'Title2', 'Attributes':['name2.90', 'name1.40', 'name1.90']}]
```

I want to iterate through this dictionary and then iterate the `'Attributes'` key in each dictionary to look for values starting with `'name1'` and not having `.90` in it, and remove it from the `'Attributes'` key.

So the final dictionary should look like:

```
Dict1 = [{'Title': 'Title1', 'Attributes':['name1.90']}, 
         {'Title': 'Title2', 'Attributes':['name2.90', 'name1.90']}]
```

I have the iteration logic as

```
for item in Dict1:
    for name in item['Attributes']:
        if 'name1' in name:
            if name.split(".")[1] not '90':
                item['Attributes'].remove(name)
```

However I see that it doesn't remove all the values that are missing `.90` in it. I tried some list comprehensions but did not help. I am new to python and coding in general, so I'm sure there is a much easier way to do this.

Comment: Don't remove items from a list you are currently iterating over (by the second `for`). Add the items you want to keep to a new list and after iterating, replace the old list with the new one.

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. You just have to replace `not '90'` by `!= '90'`

Comment: Why is `'name2.40'` removed? It does not start with `name1` so it should not be removed as per your logic because the first if statement is  `if 'name1' in name:`

Answer (score 2):

- `name.split(".")[1] not '90'` is a syntax error, just use `!=`. Python is not only a cryptic language made of `not`, `is`, `reduce`, `lambda`...
- `item['Attributes'].remove(name)` is done when you're iterating on the elements. That's bug prone: you can skip some elements

Best way is to rebuild your list of dictionaries in a list comprehension, and a dict comprehension with a filter for each dict:

```
Dict1 = [{'Title': 'Title1', 'Attributes':['name1.50', 'name2.40', 'name1.90']}, {'Title': 'Title2', 'Attributes':['name2.90', 'name1.40', 'name1.90']}]

new_dict_list = [{'Title':d['Title'], 'Attributes':[v for v in d['Attributes'] if v.endswith(".90")]} for d in Dict1]
```

result:

```
[{'Attributes': ['name1.90'], 'Title': 'Title1'},
{'Attributes': ['name2.90', 'name1.90'], 'Title': 'Title2'}]
```

with one less comprehension:

```
new_dict_list = []
for d in Dict1:
    values = [v for v in d['Attributes'] if v.endswith(".90")]
    new_dict_list.append({'Title':d['Title'], 'Attributes':values})
```

`v.endswith(".90")` could be `90 in v` or `not v.startswith('name1') and v.endswith('.90')`, not sure of the exact condition, but I'll let that to the reader.

Comment: The list comprehension here is really unreadable. It would be good if you also present an extended version with for loops. It will contain more lines but then it's not always cool to have a one liner and compromise with readability

Comment: that's a matter of getting used to it.

Comment: Yes, but especially when the OP writes in question "New to python and coding in general, ", a simpler to read solution should be provided IMO. Again, a matter of personal answering philosophy

Comment: Thanks for considering my comments. +1

Comment: as long as I don't have to "uncomprehend" the inner one :)

Comment: You don't consider the first condition OP stated: "starting with 'name1' "

Comment: As per OP's code, `'name2.40'` should not be removed. Read my comment below the question.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed breakdown!

Answer (score 0):

```
def solve():
    array = [{'Title': 'Title1', 'Attributes':['name1.50', 'name2.40', 'name1.90']}, {'Title': 'Title2', 'Attributes':['name2.90', 'name1.40', 'name1.90']}]

    for item in array:
        new_names = []
        for name in item['Attributes']:
            if '90' in name: new_names.append(name)
            elif 'name1' not in name: new_names.append(name)
        item['Attributes'] = new_names
    print(array)

solve()
```

Output: `[{'Title': 'Title1', 'Attributes': ['name2.40', 'name1.90']}, {'Title': 'Title2', 'Attributes': ['name2.90', 'name1.90']}]`

Comment: @Karthik... Please, can you mark this answer correct so that other developers come to know about it who are finding a similar issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you were very close to the right answer. In Python you can't manipulate values in a key/value pair. So instead, I tried this approach and this would produce your wanted output.

```
for x in Dict1:
    new_attributes = []
    print(x)
    for i in x['Attributes']:
        if i.split('.')[1] == '90':
            new_attributes.append(i)
    del x['Attributes'] #Not required. Can directly write the new list in the key
    x['Attributes'] = new_attributes
```

This creates a new list storing only the values you want, deletes the old `Attributes` key and creates a new one with the new list.

Comment: you don't need `del x['Attributes']`. It works without

Comment: Ah, thank you ^^.  You are correct. I'll edit my answer saying del is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will use this logic.

Comment: No problem ^^ if you found it helpful could you upvote? And mark it as solved :)